# Use \ and / on a .match()

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Well i have a little problem but really strange.

So basically i analyzed URL represented by a string. The only thing i want to check is if this URL contains 'chrome-extension://'

So basically i've tried to escape these caracter like that but it still didn't work...

```
if(!URL.match(/(chrome\-extension\:\/\/)/i))
```

Comment: `"chrome-extension://".match(/(chrome\-extension\:\/\/)/i)` works for me.

Comment: Seems to work fine on my side - http://jsfiddle.net/uFJrv/

Comment: Probably because your test string starts with (consists of) the substring whose presence he wants to detect anywhere in the string.

Comment: Works for me as well - http://jsfiddle.net/F9L97/

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker, it works the same if you put text before the search string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively:

```
if (URL.indexOf('chrome-extension://') < 0) {
    // No match
}
```

Comment: This addresses the "contains" scenario. See @vladh's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403492/use-and-on-a-match/5403554#5403554) for the "starts with" equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

String functions will be much faster than regex with such small things:

```
if(URL.substr(0,19) != "chrome-extension://")
```

Comment: “The only thing i want to check is if this URL contains 'chrome-extension://'.” – There is nothing said about the start of the string.

Comment: ...why? If it's indeed an URL the scheme will always be the first thing. Anyway, if he's sure that's what he needs, he should check jensgram's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This'll work...

```
var url = "chrome-extension://etc";
alert("match: " + url.match(/^chrome-extension:\/\//));
```

Check out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rNJ2G/).